# Trouble debugging Segmentation Error over a Linked List Function

Tags: c++

Implementing a function that inserts a new node (key = newKey) after an existing node (with key = oldkey).  If newKey isn't found in the node, then no action is performed.

This is my node constructor:

```
struct Node {
  int key;
  Node* next;
};
```

This is my method:

```
void insert_after(Node* head, int oldKey, int newKey){

  Node* currNode = NULL;
  Node* nextNode = NULL;
  Node* newNode = NULL;

  if (head == NULL) {
    return;
  }

  currNode = head; 
  newNode->key = newKey; 

  while (currNode != NULL) {

    if (currNode->key == oldKey) {

      // oldKey is anywhere but last node

      if (currNode->next != NULL) {
        nextNode = currNode->next;
        newNode->next = nextNode;
        currNode->next = newNode;
        break;
      }

      // oldKey is at the last node

      else {
        currNode->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        break;     
        }
    }

  currNode = currNode->next;
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can be reduced to: `Node* newNode = NULL; newNode->key = newKey;`

Comment: Recommendation: if you do not insert the node, warn the caller. They'll be pissed when they go looking for it later and can't find it. Even if it's their fault they can't find it. People are weird.

Comment: 2nd `break` statement is inside the `else` or is it inside the `if` ?

Comment: @KalpeshDusane That's a good question. Lack of braces put it in the outer `if` but the indentation makes it look like OP intends it to be part of the `else`. Wonder if we should warn them?

Comment: Your title says you have trouble debugging this. *What trouble* ? (besides the possibility that you simply *didn't*). Debuggers are *made* to find problem such as this, so using one should greatly assist in finding the issue.

Comment: inside the else sorry, i'll edit the code

Comment: i get a segmentation fault when i try to run this code list1 (11) with insert_after(list1, 11, 12)

Comment: What happens when you use the debugger to step over this line: `newNode->key = newKey;`?

Comment: @user4581301 unfortunately i don't have access to a debugger at the moment :(

Comment: Get one. A debugger is probably the best programming productivity tool you will ever get your hands on. [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) has a good one even in their free edition. [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/mars2) and GCC are a wee bit more troublesome but still relatively easy to set up. Even [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is better than nothing. But if you really don't have a debugger, you have the option of placing a few `std::cerr` statements to print out important variables and leave breadcrumbs.

Comment: Stick with the fundamentals. You're trying to insert a *new* node into a linked list after some node with a specified key. The operative word there is a **new** node. Nowhere in your function do you allocate a new node anywhere, so you can be confident that critical part of the task is already destined to fail. And fyi, when learning linked list data structures, paper, a pencil, drawing boxes and arrows, are *critical* tools to visualizing the tasks you're trying to accomplish. Now, don't just run back to the code, stick a `new` somewhere and cross your fingers. *Draw a diagram **first***.

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you, the problem was i wasn't allocating memory for the Node called "newNode".

Comment: @jamessxiao that would definitely be a problem. Fyi, now that you think you have it solved, if I understand your problem, [it could be much simpler](http://pastebin.com/W4HDv8z2) than you seem to be making it. If the intent is to (a) never insert on a null list, (b) always insert after the first occurrence of `oldKey`, (c) otherwise, insert to the end of the list, the link in this comment is a much more direct way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to dereference a null pointer:

```
currNode = head;
newNode->key = newKey;  // <-- newNode is NULL

if (head == NULL) {
```

Also, this is C++; no need to declare all variables at the beginning of the scope.  Declare and initialize variables as they are needed to help avoid this.  For example, this is more obviously wrong:

```
Node* newNode = NULL;   // or "nullptr" if using C++11
newNode->key = newKey;
```

Comment: yes thank you; the problem was that i did not allocate memory for the Node "newNode".